# What is the last event that fires when creating features

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am doing an Ajax lookup on a checkbox click that retrieves lat/lng and creates markers on the map. I have a loading gif that displays to alert the user that the Ajax lookup is in process, and remove the gif when the lat/lngs are returned and the markers are made. However, from the user's perspective, the loading gif disappears and several seconds later the markers appear.

What is the last event that fires in this process? I want to remove my loading gif not when the code says that the markers are created, but after they actually display on the map.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would try the ["idle" event](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map).